# Getting "Cannot POST" with registration page using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm sure there's a sound reason as to why I can't get this to work but I've been staring at the code for a long time and I'm brutally stuck. I'm trying to build out a very basic registration form that should store the data in my PostgreSQL database. I'm using bcrypt to hash out the password, but even without still having issues.

My HTML has the following:

```
<form action="/register/new" method="post">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <label for="confirm">Confirm Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="confirm">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then for the code I have:

```
app.get("/register", function(req,res){
  res.render("register");
})

app.post('register', function(req,res){
  let newUser = {
    username: req.body.username,
    passwordHash: bcrypt.hashSynce(req.body.password, 8)
  }
  models.Users.create(newUser).then(function(){
    res.redirect('/login');
   })
 });
```

The plan for the registration data to be stored and the user redirected to the login page, login stores them in session, and so on. I thought for a bit that the issue was the action on the form but regardless I'm getting Cannot POST /register/new. I've also played around with doing a findOrCreate and do a comparison but I wanted to start with actually just creating before I make it more complex. The same issue occurs with cannot post.

Any thoughts on what I need to change?

Comment: are you using csrf tokens?

Answer (score 1):

Probably would've worked better if I did a app.post("/register"...

Simple miss of an "/"

Answer (score 0):

try this modified code...

```
app.post('/register', function(req,res) {
  let newUser = {
    username: req.body.username,
    passwordHash: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, 8)
  }
  // if it does not connect/save try using models.User instead of models.Users below.
  models.Users.create(newUser).then(function(){
    res.location('/login');
    res.redirect('/login');
  })
});
```